# Separator between the bar in MS chart

Tags: c#, asp.net, mschart

Is it possible to have separator between the bar in MS chart. Similar to white separator in below image.

[image: separation between section1, section2 and section3, section4 required]

I am using microsoft chart 3.5 to plot the graphs. I want separation between section1, section2 and section3, section4.

Please help how we can achieve this through c#.

Thanks.

Comment: You could make a chart area for each section and put all the chart areas on the same chart control. http://i.imgur.com/aUi4DIg.png

Comment: Add a `StripLine` to your chart.